# how to make php search for similar words

Tags: php

i have a searchbox in which user can give input.This input text will be searched in database and results are retrieved through the syntax..

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM new WHERE FNAME LIKE '%$a%' LIMIT 0, 30 ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        {
        echo '<tr>';
         echo $row["FNAME"];
        echo '<br>';
        echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
}
```

its working but my problem is i want to make search for similar words.
eg if anyone searches emran and my database must have to give imran.....

Comment: This is a very complicated problem to solve. There is no simple way to do that with just one simple SQL query. You will have to build some kind of search index that allows you to retrieve terms similar to the given term and then locate the entries associated with it. Finding "similar" terms can range all the way from "swap a few letters and see if it matches", over scoring functions all the way to text mining and machine learning. ;) That will clearly not fit into the format of SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are searching user specific names then there is no such direct method which will give you appropriate results even after user makes any spelling mistakes while searching.

It's like building your own algorithm which will first look for direct match if not found then it will look for to detect similar names and return result.

Other option I think of is creating another column which will store all the common spelling mistakes happen while typing original name, In your case column `FNAME` will contain imran and `FNAME_SEARCH`(any name as per requirement) which will contain common mistakes are made like emraan, omran, etc.

So your query will look like this,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM new WHERE FNAME LIKE '%$a%' OR FNAME_SEARCH LIKE '%$a%' LIMIT 0, 30 ";
```

Comment: ya sir that idea came into my mind..but problem is i have a lots of fieds and many number of row has to be inserted....not only name i have have to accept searches for other fields also .....approximately i have to make atleast 4000 duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Just change where clause to

```
where soundex(FNAME) = soundex('$a')
```

or

```
where FNAME sounds like '$a'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to build your query depending on the first character that was passed as the search string. If the first character is a Vowel (a, e, o, i, u), you could run a function to build up all the possible combinations using those vowels. Here is what is meant:

```
    <?php
        $searchTerm     = 'emran';
        $probableTerms  = buildProbableSearchTerms($searchTerm);

        $sql    = "SELECT * FROM new WHERE FNAME LIKE '{$probableTerms}' LIMIT 0, 30 ";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo $row["FNAME"];
                    echo '<br>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
            }
        }

        function buildProbableSearchTerms($searchTerm){
            $searchTerms    = "";
            if(strlen($searchTerm)<1){
                return "";
            }
            $arrVowels  = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u");
            $arrSString = str_split($searchTerm);
            if(in_array(strtolower($arrSString[0]), $arrVowels)){
                array_splice($arrSString, 0, 1);
                foreach($arrVowels as $vowel){
                    $searchTerms .= "%{$vowel}" . implode("", $arrSString) . "% OR ";
                }
                $searchTerms = rtrim($searchTerms, " OR ");
            }else{
                $searchTerms .= "%{$searchTerm}%";
            }
            return $searchTerms;

        }



        var_dump($probableTerms);
        // DISPLAYS: '%amran% OR %emran% OR %imran% OR %omran% OR %umran%'
```